# Roo Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `Roo Gem` to read excel files but facing a challenge. I'm converting all float and integers to string but it doesn't give me the values I want. 
Below is my implementation

```
file = 'path/to/file.xlsx'    
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)

header = xlsx.sheet(0).row(1)

(2..xlsx.sheet(0).last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, xlsx.row(i).map(&:to_s)].transpose]
end
```

If the float in the excel file is `3200.00`, I want it as `'3200.00'` as a string. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Why u need float value as string? Whether table column is string or float datatype?

Comment: @NatarajaB Yes, I need it as a string irrespective of the column datatype. I'm using it to compare an array from a different source.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use map! instead of map

```
file = 'path/to/file.xlsx'    
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)

header = xlsx.sheet(0).row(1)

(2..xlsx.sheet(0).last_row).each do |i|
   row = Hash[[header, xlsx.row(i).map!(&:to_s)].transpose]
end
```